# Css Grid with dynamic content

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a list with items aligned to each other using a grid.

[here you can see a picture of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwSrm.png)

but anyway I'm trying to align grid rows 2 and 3 next to each other (the content of 2 is dynamic)
but I'm kind of having trouble because every time I try it affects the other rows.
does anyone have an idea how i can solve this?

Comment: It would be easier to understand your question if you would include your code into it.